# MySQL select each column average without specifying all columns

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to look up how to compute the average of each column using SQL. However, every single example I can find either explicitly specifies the columns, like so:

```
SELECT AVG(column1), AVG(column2), ...
FROM table;
```

Or it will specify how to aggregate results across columns to form some kind of grand mean, like so:

```
SELECT (AVG(column1)+AVG(column2)+...)/n_columns
FROM table;
```

What I'm looking for is a way to take a table that looks like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |

And get a result that looks like this:

| AVG(column1) | AVG(column2) | AVG(column3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 3.5 | 5.5 |

Without having to tediously list every single column in the SELECT statement. From here I hope to tack on various groupings and joins, so if one needs to use some kind of "hack" to make this work, it would need to be a very extensible hack.

I naively hoped I might be able to try something like

```
SELECT AVG(*)
FROM table;
```

And have it work out. I was maybe 20% hopeful that it could be this simple, but alas, this was not valid syntax, and as aforementioned, trying to search for the answer to what I thought was a relatively simple problem has proven very aggravating.

Comment: Noway. You MUST write separate expression for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that but there's a workaround using [PREPARED STATEMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html).

Here's an example:

1. I'm using two separate variables for easy understanding:

```
SET @columns := NULL;
SET @sql := NULL;
```

2. First up is to generate columns using `information_schema.columns` table:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('AVG(',column_name,')')) INTO @columns
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema='fiddle'
   AND table_name='Table1';
```

3. Then use that generated columns in `@columns` variable to create a query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@columns,' FROM Table1;') INTO @sql;
```

4. Finally, prepare, execute then deallocate the statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You can also create the final query using a single syntax like this:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',
              GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('AVG(',column_name,')')),' 
     FROM ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') INTO @sql
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema='fiddle'
   AND table_name='Table1';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dDdrYKh2)